# mongodb aggregation result exceeds maximum document size

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to retrieved an "unwinded" version of my document, but the result exceeds the maximum size allowed.
This is the aggregation I'm working on:

```
var result = collection.Aggregate(
            new BsonDocument {{"$unwind", "$Surgeries"}},
            new BsonDocument {{"$unwind", "$Surgeries.Procedures"}},
            new BsonDocument {{"$unwind", "$Surgeries.Procedures.ScannedItems"}},
            new BsonDocument
                {
                    {
                        "$project", new BsonDocument
                            {
                                {"_id", 0},
                                {"PatientAgeId", 1},
                                {"PatientAge", 1},
                                {"PatientBMIId", 1},
                                {"PatientASAId", 1},
                                {"PatientASA", 1},
                                {"PatientBMI", 1},
                                {"ClientId", "$Surgeries.Procedures.ClientId"},
                                {"PhysicianId", "$Surgeries.Procedures.PhysicianId"},
                                {"ProcedureTypeName", "$Surgeries.Procedures.ProcedureTypeName"},
                                {"Item_CategoryName", "$Surgeries.Procedures.ScannedItems.CategoryName"},
                                {"Item_ManufacturerName", "$Surgeries.Procedures.ManufacturerName"},
                                {"Item_ItemClassName", "$Surgeries.Procedures.ScannedItems.ItemClassName"},
                                {"Item_ItemGroupName", "$Surgeries.Procedures.ScannedItems.ItemGroupName"},
                                {"Item_PriceTypeId", "$Surgeries.Procedures.ScannedItems.PriceTypeId"},
                                {"Item_Cost", "$Surgeries.Procedures.ScannedItems.ActualCost"}
                            }
                    }
                });
```

Is it possible to use GridFS to achieved this?

I already read that it is possible to use $skip operator and loop through the collection with more than one aggregation and merge results. How would that affect the performance? Is that a good practice?

Comment: You may want to have a look at the [allowDiskUse](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/). Since I have no idea of C#, all I can do is to direct you to http://stackoverflow.com/a/24872644/1296707

Comment: What version of MongoB are you using?

Comment: @wdberkeley mongoDB version is 1.8.3.9

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Checking :)