# How do I add AggregateOptions in an IMongoQueryable?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I am getting an error below

> Command aggregate failed: Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600
> bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation.
> Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in..

Below is my sample code that has a lot of sorting and has big data. How do I allowDiskUse to true based on my sample below?

```
var collection = _context.GetCollection<SampleCollection>();

var result = collection.AsQueryable();

result = result.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
    .ThenByDescending(d => d.Status)
    .ThenByDescending(r => r.Firstname)
    .ThenByDescending(d => d.Lastname)
    .ThenByDescending(d => d.Birthdate)
    .ThenByDescending(d => d.Sex);

return result .ToList();
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, `allowDiskUse` is only able to use with `.Aggregate()`. I doubt it works with `IQueryable`. You may refer to this question: [allowDiskUse in Aggregation Framework with MongoDB C# Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24855696/8017690)

Answer (score 0):

See below:

```
        var client = new MongoClient();
        var db = client.GetDatabase("db");
        var collection = db.GetCollection<SampleCollection>("c");
        var result = collection.AsQueryable<SampleCollection>(new AggregateOptions() { AllowDiskUse = true });

        var res = result.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
            .ThenByDescending(d => d.Status)
            .ToList();
```